# ios Can you change the Bundle Identifier of your project?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to change the bundle identifier for my project, but the end of its text is grey and the edit box is not allowing me to change it.

I'm trying to change it under  the summery tab where under ios application targert it says bundle identifier, then has a edit box to the right of it.

The bundle identifier is
com.ted.firstapp
I want to change it to 
com.ted.firstapp2
but it will only allow mr to chnage
com.ted
all the text after the last perdiod is greyed and I cannot chnage it.

Comment: In target properties -> info tab, change Bundle Name different than "${PRODUCT_NAME}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it inside the `info.plist`

open it as source code, search the `CFBundleIdentifier` and change it

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.ted.firstapp2</string>
```